# Any suggestions for a adobe indesign like body field?

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

I'm on d7. I am looking for any suggestions on modules that can give me the functionality to have a field that acts like adobe indesign. (For the purpose of this explanation I am going to call this my "canvas" field) I would like for my canvas field to be a container that holds text/images/videos/audio instead of just text like a body field would. I would like to provide my users with the ability to write some text in a something like a text box and be able to resize and position it where they want in the "container" field along with images etc. Does anyone have any suggestions? Even a combination of modules or something to get me started would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The WYSIWYG module http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg will allow you to offer a rich text editor for your users. You can combine that with the Media module http://drupal.org/project/media to embed media files. It won't be like indesign exactly but will allow users to have some freedom with the content.